# SQL Get record from table 2 that immediately follows record in table 1 and only return that record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data like so and for some reason it's just not clicking for me right now:

| cid | cmt_date | comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | LTR |
| 2 | 2023-02-01 | RTR |

Here is an example of table 2

| pid | pmt_date | payment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-03-01 | 100 |

I would want to see the following back:

| cid | comment_date | comment | pmt_date | pmt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2023-02-01 | RTR | 2023-03-01 | 100 |

Each table has about 400,000 records in them, there could be 20 records in table 1 and only 1 record in table 2.

I did something like this:

```
SELECT 
    t1.cid, t1.cmt_date AS comment_date, t1.comment, 
    t2.pmt_date, t2.payment AS pmt
FROM
    table1 t1
INNER JOIN 
    table2 t2 ON t2.pmt_date > t1.cmt_date 
              AND t1.pt_no = t2.pt_no
```

`pt_no` is like an invoice number and is used for a join on the same invoice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CROSS APPLY with a subquery to get just 1, "most recent", row from table2 for each row in table1:

```
SELECT t1.cid, t1.cmt_date AS comment_date, t1.comment, t2.pmt_date, t2.payment AS pmt
FROM table1 t1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM table2
    WHERE pmt_date > t1.cmt_date AND pt_no = t1.pt_no
    ORDER BY pmt_date DESC
) t2
```

Change the ordering to `ORDER BY pmt_date ASC` to get one row with the closest date to t1.cmt_date (I wasn't sure which option you wanted). You might also want to use `>=` in the subquery comparison (again I can't be sure of this).

Comment: I changed DESC to ASC and it worked like a charm